# Get Rectangle from index in a tilemap

Tags: c#, xna, grid, 2d, tile

I have some tilemaps where all tiles are 64x64 pixels.
I need to know the position of an tile if know the index in the tilemap.
How I can do this in C#?

Comment: there is question that I believe should be added to the FAQ, it's `What have you tried so far?`

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to divide the total width to 64 and multiply to 64+index, but it don't work and I have no clue how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you to find the x and y coords of the tile:

```
int tileY = tileIndex / numberOfTiles;
int tileX = (tileIndex % numberOfTiles) - 1;
```

numberOfTiles refers to the number of tiles in the x direction of the tile map, e.g. if the tile map was 16 tiles wide and 20 tiles high, numberOfTiles would be 16. to get the other 2 coords just add the tile height to tileY and the tile width to tileX.